# How do I terminate the application if help option is specified on the command line?

Tags: c#, command-line, .net-core

This question is about a family of classes the work together in .net core to provide rich command line parsing experience. The main class is [CommandLineApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.commandlineutils.commandlineapplication). [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt763239.aspx) is an article that walk trough main facilities.

This is how one configures help option that shows automatically generated help.

```
cla.HelpOption("-? | -h | --help");
```

I want my application to *terminate* if the help option was found anywhere on the command line, instead of keeping running. But I cannot find a nice way of achieving this. I of course could parse the arguments myself to find if the option is specified, but is not the whole point of this facility to do this for me?

Here is sample code I'm using:

```
public class Config
{
    public string Option1 {get; set;}
}

public class CommandLine
{
    public static void ApplyCommandLineArguments(string[] args, Config config)
    {
        CommandLineApplication cla = new CommandLineApplication(false);
        CommandOption option1 = cla.Option(
            "-o | --option1",
            "Set this option to specify option1",
            CommandOptionType.SingleValue
        );
        cla.HelpOption("-? | -h | --help");
        cla.OnExecute(() =>
        {
            if (option1.HasValue())
            {
                config.Option1 = option1.Value();
            }
            return 0;
        });

        try
        {
            cla.Execute(args);
        }
        catch (CommandParsingException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            cla.ShowHelp();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the `Main` method:

```
Config config = new Config();
CommandLine.ApplyCommandLineArguments(args, config);
// I want to exit here if user specified the help option anywhere on the command line.
Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
```

Comment: By just looking at it I'd say it seems you are supposed to execute the code inside `if (option1.HasValue())` (or make it set `config.Option1 = true` and then check that in your main code).

Comment: @VisualVincent, this is quite obvious to me,but how does value of `option1` could possible help here? What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know how that library works, but by looking at it it would seem that `option1.HasValue()` returns `true` when one of the commands exist. It then sets `config.Option1` to that value. Have you tried inspecting the variables using a debugger?

Comment: @VisualVincent, sorry my point is, that my question is not about setting or examining whatever Option1 stores or set to. Thus I'm failing to see how any of that would bring us closer to the goal.

Comment: You wanted to terminate the application if the command line contained the "help" option, right? To do so you must know which variable or method can tell you that it does, and since I have no idea how this library works all I can do is give suggestions from my perspective.

Comment: **And from what I saw** it looked like the "help" option would be put in `Option1` if it existed in the command line. So I thought: _"Why not examine that?"_ -- Anyway, you've got your answer now, which turned out to be rather simple. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent *"You wanted to terminate the application if the command line contained the "help" option, right?"* Exactly. *" it looked like the "help" option would be put in Option1"*, no, not at all ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If help option was found, `cla.Execute` will not actually run your `OnExecute` callback and will just return 0. You can use it by returning non-zero value from your `OnExecute` callback, like this:

```
public class CommandLine
{
    // returns true if parse was successful and you can proceed. Returns false if you can terminate
    public static bool ApplyCommandLineArguments(string[] args, Config config)
    {
        CommandLineApplication cla = new CommandLineApplication(false);
        CommandOption option1 = cla.Option(
            "-o | --option1",
            "Set this option to specify option1",
            CommandOptionType.SingleValue
        );
        cla.HelpOption("-? | -h | --help");
        cla.OnExecute(() =>
        {
            if (option1.HasValue()) {
                config.Option1 = option1.Value();
            }
            // non-zero value
            return 1;
        });

        try {
            int result = cla.Execute(args);
            // check result
            return result > 0;
        }
        catch (CommandParsingException ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            cla.ShowHelp();
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Config config = new Config();
        if (!CommandLine.ApplyCommandLineArguments(args, config)) {
            return;
        }

        // I want to exit here if user specified the help option anywhere on the command line.
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: You'd probably want to call `ShowHelp` on the `ex.Command` in order to display the help of the corresponding command.